# API Call from java, weird results?

Tags: java, php, json, api

So i am working on a project that involves a java application making calls to our API. It has to send data over GET and up until this point i could do it without any problems, however, i am trying to send a json string as one of the GET parameters.

Now, on the API, the GET variable will be empty when the call is made, however if i use 'print_r' or 'var_dump' on the API page when it is called, it magically works. (Obvious sarcasam)

I know that might sound confusing, that would be because it is. I havent had any problems making my calls up until this point.

My non-working code: (throws one of the errors.)

PHP

```
$checking = array(1, 2, 3);
$data = json_decode(base64_decode(urldecode($_GET['update'])), true);
if(!isset($data))
{
    exit(json_encode(array("Error"=>"Invalid data")));

}
if(count($data) != count($checking))
{
    exit(json_encode(array("Error"=>"Invalid amount: ")));
}
```

JAVA

```
List<HashMap<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

for(ClientBase pb : this.clients)
{
    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("id", pb.id);
    map.put("type", pb.getType());
    map.put("status", pb.getStatus() ? 1 : 0);
    list.add(map);
}

String out = JSONObject.valueToString(list);
String newout = new String(Base64.encode(out.getBytes()));
URLConnection conn = new URL("http://localhost/api/?key=" + Main.INSTANCE.APIKEY + "&update=" + URLEncoder.encode(newout, "UTF- 8")).openConnection();
InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
res = s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
```

This results in one of the errors getting thrown due to the array being empty/null.

Now, if i change my PHP code to:

```
$checking = array(1, 2, 3);
$data = json_decode(base64_decode(urldecode($_GET['update'])), true);
var_dump($data);
if(!isset($data))
{
    exit(json_encode(array("Error"=>"Invalid data")));

}
if(count($data) != count($checking))
{
    exit(json_encode(array("Error"=>"Invalid amount: ")));
}
```

then the $data array is populated and no error gets thrown.

I really cant wrap my head around this one, Also i base64 encoded it and urlencoded it in an effort to get this to work.

Thanks for any help

Comment: *i am trying to send a json string as one of the GET parameters* ... but why? There are `POST` and `PUT` for that purpose, don't simulate the request body with a `GET` parameter.

Comment: Thats true, however does it actually make any difference in this matter? I dont see why that would cause such a strange "bug"? @BackSlash

Comment: Im going to convert the API to POST quickly, hopefully that will fix this.

Comment: Of course that isn't the issue. It's just something you want to stay away from, before you make a huge mess and your code becomes unmaintainable. As for your issue, `print_r` and `var_dump` don't make things magically work, and your code is actually incomplete (what is `$session`? what is `list`?) so I think you would have to do some debugging yourself.

Comment: Updated the question @BackSlash

Comment: You should never have to use `urldecode()` on a `$_GET` variable, PHP automatically decodes the request information before populating the super-globals. You may also be running into caching problems, yet another reason to **not** use a GET request

Comment: FYI, if `json_decode()` is returning `null`, it means it encountered an error. You can see this error via [`json_last_error_msg()`](http://php.net/manual/function.json-last-error-msg.php)

Comment: I tried your code, it works for me. It gives errore for "invalid amount" when I pass more than 3 elements from java, but it works. It reads the input correctly. Likely your issue is somewhere else in the code, maybe something is erasing that variable before this specific code is reached.